# How to search unordered words?

Tags: php, mysql

I need an unordered word search to get any matches in the MySQL database. For example, if I type 'call of duty' in the search input, the output is correct, but the code below returns an empty array if I type 'duty of call'.

```
// parse post request
$s = isset($_POST["s"]) ? trim(htmlspecialchars($cn->real_escape_string(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $_POST["s"])))) : "";

// split search string into spaces
$split  = explode(" ", $s);
$sCount = count($split);

$s = "%".$s."%";

// generate mysql query string
$q = "SELECT source,title,description,link FROM feeds USE INDEX(idx_title,idx_descr,idx_pubdate)WHERE(title LIKE '$s' OR description LIKE '$s') ";
$oq = "";

if ($sCount > 1) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $sCount; ++$i){
        $ss  = "%".$split[$i]."%";
        $q  .= "AND(title LIKE '$ss' OR description LIKE '$ss')";
        $oq .= "AND(title LIKE '$ss' OR description LIKE '$ss')";
    }
}
$q .= "ORDER BY pubdate ".$oq."DESC LIMIT 60";
```

Here is the generated query string for each search parameter from the code above:

**"call of duty"->**

```
SELECT source,title,description,link 
FROM feeds 
    USE INDEX(idx_title,idx_descr,idx_pubdate) 
WHERE (title LIKE '%call of duty%' OR description LIKE '%call of duty%') 
AND (title LIKE '%call%' OR description LIKE '%call%') 
AND (title LIKE '%of%' OR description LIKE '%of%') 
AND (title LIKE '%duty%' OR description LIKE '%duty%') 
ORDER BY pubdate 
AND (title LIKE '%call%' OR description LIKE '%call%') 
AND (title LIKE '%of%' OR description LIKE '%of%') 
AND (title LIKE '%duty%' OR description LIKE '%duty%') DESC 
LIMIT 60
```

**"duty of call"->**

```
SELECT source,title,description,link 
FROM feeds 
    USE INDEX(idx_title,idx_descr,idx_pubdate) 
WHERE (title LIKE '%duty of call%' OR description LIKE '%duty of call%') 
AND (title LIKE '%duty%' OR description LIKE '%duty%') 
AND (title LIKE '%of%' OR description LIKE '%of%') 
AND (title LIKE '%call%' OR description LIKE '%call%') 
ORDER BY pubdate 
AND (title LIKE '%duty%' OR description LIKE '%duty%') 
AND (title LIKE '%of%' OR description LIKE '%of%') 
AND (title LIKE '%call%' OR description LIKE '%call%') DESC 
LIMIT 60
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks i know that i'm alredy using $st = $cn->prepare($q); $st->execute();

Comment: Ok but prepared statements only prevent SQL injection when used together with **parameters**, which you aren't using here.

Comment: PS, if you can see/read it maybe you/we can debug it

Comment: Anyway, just remove the `(title LIKE '%duty of call%' OR description LIKE '%duty of call%')` bit from your query and you should be good (that is essentially redundant / limiting, since you're also searching for all the words separately anyway) - although you forgot to show us what's actually in the table, so we have to assume it has the exact phrase "call of duty" somewhere in the target string, without any other text between it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's done. The ordered search works, but the unordered search does not.

Comment: @ADyson I can't remove it because if there is a single word, the query string will be empty.

Comment: Get rid of the `if ($sCount > 1) {` test as well, then you'll always generate at least one clause. (Just make sure, if it's the first one, not to prepend the `AND`.)

Comment: `please don't downvote if you can't understand the question`...why not? "Unclear" is one of the documented downvote reasons. Questions should be clear...it doesn't seem unreasonable to me (although I didn't add the downvote myself, but it could have been justified before it was edited. Ideally it should still have a data sample included too, though). See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down . A question can also be closed entirely for lacking clarity, so a downvote is a far gentler indication really.

Comment: P.S. All this `AND (title LIKE '%call%' OR description LIKE '%call%') 
AND (title LIKE '%of%' OR description LIKE '%of%') 
AND (title LIKE '%duty%' OR description LIKE '%duty%')` in the ORDER BY clause makes no sense as far as I can see. Each of those expressions will evaluate to true or false, not column names. I think you can just get rid of that.

Comment: @ADyson The question is clear and if you read it you will understand it. I'm asking because the first variant of the search parameter is working and the second is not while words like 'call', 'of', and 'duty' exist in the MySQL database.

Comment: What you might really be interested in is [full text searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html), rather than mess with multiple where's. You can even do a full text against multiple columns.

Comment: The formatting and presentation wasn't very clear though - particularly the code, until it was reformatted by RiggsFolly. Jumbling your SQL all together on one line makes it much harder to comprehend. I'd assume you don't write code in that manner normally. And we're still lacking a sample of the database data you're searching against for 100% clarity (albeit in this case we can make a good guess, but that's not always true in every question.)

Comment: The problem with your last query is that you have `WHERE (title LIKE '%duty of call%' OR description LIKE '%duty of call%') 
AND (title LIKE '%duty%' OR description LIKE '%duty%') 
AND (title LIKE '%of%' OR description LIKE '%of%') 
AND (title LIKE '%call%' OR description LIKE '%call%')` -- the first group specifies that one of the fields **must** have `duty of call`, no matter what the rest of the searches contain. So it won't match `call of duty` at all. Removing that clause and doing just the rest of the where's will fix your query, as long as you add the WHERE/AND in the right places

Comment: `I'm asking because the first variant of the search parameter is working and the second is not while words like 'call', 'of', and 'duty' exist in the MySQL database.`...well of course not, because of the first bit of the WHERE clause requiring a match for the whole phrase (rather than individual words). And I've already explained what you can do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

```
(title LIKE '%duty of call%' OR description LIKE '%duty of call%')
```

requires that one of the fields must have an exact match to that specific phrase in that order. If the target data doesn't have that, it won't return anything. This appears to be contrary to your stated requirements.

I suggest refactoring your code to remove that check, and instead ensuring you generate at least one of the single-word checking expressions. Something like this:

```
$s = isset($_POST["s"]) ? trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $_POST["s"])) : "";

// split search string into spaces
$split  = explode(" ", $s);
$sCount = count($split);

// generate mysql query string
$q = "SELECT source, title, description, link FROM feeds USE INDEX(idx_title, idx_descr, idx_pubdate) WHERE ";
$params = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $sCount; ++$i){
    if ($sCount > 1) $q .= " AND ";
    $q  .= " (title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?)";
    $ss = "%".$split[$i]."%";
    $params[] = $ss;
    $params[] = $ss; //use twice, once for each ?
}

$q .= "ORDER BY pubdate DESC LIMIT 60";
```

---

P.S. I have replaced the direct injection of data in this code with `?` placeholders, to prevent SQL injection and related issues. You can then pass the values in as parameters via the `bind_param` function or in recent versions of PHP, by directly including the `$params` array as an argument to `execute()` before you execute the query. If you're using parameters you also don't need the `real_escape_string` function and should remove it. `htmlspecialchars` is also an *output* filter and has nothing to do with parsing input. At best it achieves nothing useful in this context, but at worst it could corrupt your search term. I expect/assume/hope you didn't also process the stored data in this way before storing it in the database. That function should only be used when *outputting* data, and only when outputting into a *HTML document*, where XSS attacks could be a risk.

P.P.S. Including the generated `WHERE` clause elements in the `ORDER BY` clause really makes no sense as far as I can see - those expressions evaluate to true/false, rather than a column name - so I removed that too.